Deployando un proyecto con Render: ModuleNotFoundError
Actulamente me encuentro en la version de despliegue de mi proyecto, lo queremos subir a la web utilizando el servicio Render, pero tenemos un error que en todos los videos que vimos de gente utilizando este mismo servicio no les sucede.
brevemente el mensaje habla sobre que no encuentra un modulo. Especificamente el wsgi.
Adjunto unas imagenes de referencia




Parece que el error que estás experimentando está relacionado con la configuración del módulo WSGI en tu aplicación web. Sería útil revisar la configuración de tu proyecto y asegurarte de que el módulo WSGI esté correctamente configurado y accesible para la aplicación en Render.

Hola andrea, un gusto por tomarte el tiempo en responder. Este es mi wsgi:
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'back.settings')
application = get_wsgi_application()
